# Elasticity of Substitution (CES)

Tags: economics, utility

This appears to be a nice forum. I just registered since I have a question...

I have a CES aggregator-function
$$
f(c,q) = (r c^{a} + b q^{a})^{1/a}.
$$
It is postulated that it can be rewritten as
$$
f(c,q) = c \left[ r + b \left( \frac{q}{c} \right)^{a} \right]^{\frac{1}{a}}.
$$

I don’t see how, and neither does Maple. Can anyone help? I’m confused and I don’t know what I have missed. I bet that there is insufficient information.

Thanks for the edit; I will write the problem in the correct language now.

Comment: This is valid if $c > 0$.

Comment: It was enough! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $c = (c^a) ^{\frac {1}{a}}$ if $c > 0$.